React + Vite Reusable Component Error: Failed to resolve import Does the file exist?
I'm trying to create a reusable component for my react project (using Vite). For some reason I keep getting the error that it can't resolve the import. In my dev environment everything seems to be fine (all paths are recognized)
Am I missing a step?
Here is what I have:
ClientSearchForm.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { z } from "zod"
import { clientSearchFormSchema } from "constants/schemas/clientList"
import {Panel, PanelHeader, PanelTitle } from "components/ui/panel"

 export function ClientSearchForm() {

     return (
         <>
        <Panel>
            <PanelHeader>
                <PanelTitle />
            </PanelHeader>
        </Panel>
    </>)
}

ClientSearchPage.tsx
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
//import { ClientSearchForm } from 'features/client';
import { ClientSearchForm } from "features/client/components/ClientSearchForm";

const ClientSearchPage = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <ClientSearchForm />
        </>
    )

};

export default ClientSearchPage;


Routes.tsx
import { lazy } from 'react';
const Index = lazy(() => import('../pages/Index'));
const Diagnostic = lazy(() => import('../pages/Dashboards/Diagnostic'));
const Supervision = lazy(() => import('../pages/Dashboards/Supervision'));
const ClientSearch = lazy(() => import('../pages/Modules/Client/ClientSearchPage'));

const routes = [
    // default
    {
        path: '/',
        element: <Index />,
        layout: 'default',
    },
    // Diagnostic Dashboard
    {
        path: '/dashboards/diagnostic',
        element: <Diagnostic />
    },
    // Supervision Dashboard
    {
        path: '/dashboards/supervision',
        element: <Supervision />
    },
    // Client Search
    {
        path: '/modules/client',
        element: <ClientSearch />
    }

];

export { routes };


ERROR:
[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "features/client/components/ClientSearchForm" from "src/pages/Modules/Client/ClientSearchPage.tsx". Does the file exist?

Have you tried switching to the relative path?

Thank you @Odri This solved the issue.  I tried to mess with tsconfig to avoid having to do this. I couldnt get it to play nice. Here is my current setting:  "baseUrl": "./src",

try to add this to your vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import path from 'path'

// https://vite.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    sourcemap: true,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),
    },
  },
})

and inside your tsconfig.json file you can add the following settings:
   "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    },

this way you can import your files like @/components/ui/panel. Maybe if you play with the settings you can also get rid of "@/".
